# Return content based on REQUEST_URI by PHP

Tags: php

Say, My domain is 'www.miraj.com'. If users click on the link 'www.miraj.com/childhood-of-miraj' then I want to check my database if there is any post having the title 'childhood-of-miraj' it should be shown otherwise 404 page will be shown. But since there is no directory(folder) named 'childhood-of-miraj' it immediately returns 404 page. How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at .htaccess rewrite rules, that's normally how I see it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the **httpd** you are using (Apache or Nginx).

For **Apache**, you should edit your .htaccess file to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ FileToHandleDatabaseSearch.php?title=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will transform the URL on fly www.miraj.com/childhood-of-miraj to www.miraj.com/FileToHandleDatabaseSearch.php?childhood-of-miraj on the server, not in browser address bar. 
**FileToHandleDatabaseSearch.php**

```php
if (isset($_GET['title'])) {
    //...Search DB for $title
    //If title exists display page with title
    //If title does not exist display 404 page not found
}
```

For **NGINX** you edit that in the conf file
**www.miraj.com.conf** in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` should look like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /path/to/project/root;
    server_name www.miraj.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    rewrite ^([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ FileToHandleDatabaseSearch.php?title=$1 last;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

You would want to prefix the paths to be object-specific to avoid URL conflicts. For example if `childhood-of-miraj` is a movie title let the rewrite conditions be `rewrite ^/movies/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ "/path/to/project/root/FileToHandleDatabaseSearch.php?title=$1" last;`

You can visit [Apache Rewrite Rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) for more **.htaccess** rules you can employ and [Nginx Rewrite Rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) for more Nginx rules you can employ.